# Rename Connection Name and Add JSF action Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

This is my first work with jsPlumb and it's amazing, but i want to know how can i add connection name label dynamically ? also how can i add an events like the doubleClick event of ajax to get a pop-up, this is how i add statemachine-demo Nodes :

```
<ui:repeat var="step" value="#{stepController.steps}" varStatus="status">
    <div class="w" id="opened#{status.index}">
             #{status.index} #{step.label} 
        <div class="ep">
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for overlay type 'label'.

Docs - https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/overlays.html#type-label

```
var c = jsPlumb.connect({
  source:"d1", 
  target:"d2", 
  overlays:[
    [ "Label", {label:"FOO", id:"label"}]
  ] 
});
```

Talking about dblclick event, just attach it as you would do for a normal html element and it should work, if it doesn't paste the code of what you're trying to do and someone from here will be able to help.